# Jquery form ajax call trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having trouble submitting an ajax request.

I've tried to set it up pretty simply just to see if i can get a response

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mainform').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "processform_ajax.php",
                        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
                        dataType: "json",
                        sucess: function (data) {
                                alert("data" . data);
                                //$("#response").append(data);
                        },
                        error: function(error, txt) {
                                alert(error.status);
                        }
                }); 
       });
});
```

My php is simply this

```
<?php
        $errors = array ('a' => 'TEST!');
        echo json_encode($errors);
?>
```

When I try to run this with the firebug extension i'm seeing the post looks okay. (which it shouldn't matter at this point, because my php just echo's out something)

On the response side I'm seeing this error : NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Which leads me to believe it can't find processform_ajax.php, but when i've tried the absolute url in url: "" option above. I can also hit the the php script through the browser's address bar and get the json response

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: In firebug, make sure when you click the down arrow on the console tab, Show XMLHttpRequests is ticked, you should get the URL the ajax call is going to - is THIS url correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE` seems like a Firefox "bug/feature" where it tries to submit the call twice.

Try this... add a `return false` in your code, like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mainform').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    ...
                }); 

                return false;
       });
});
```

This way, once the form is submitted through your JS code, the `return false` will prevent your "Submit" button from submitting the same request again.

Comment: This did the trick. Out of all the documentation i looked through nothing mentioned this. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Is **sucess** a typo in your code, or just on SO?

Comment: typo in my code, but it wasn't working regardless. The return false did it.